# Org Mode: Issue with repeated tasks

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I started getting this issue with repeated tasks now.  Assume I have a task like this:

```
** TODO test task
   SCHEDULED: <2013-11-12 Tue + 1m>
```

I want to close and schedule it for next month. So I do <kbd>C-c C-t</kbd>. After doing this I get the following:

```
** DONE test task
   CLOSED: [2013-11-12 Tue 17:10] SCHEDULED: <2013-11-12 Tue + 1m>
   - CLOSING NOTE [2013-11-12 Tue 17:10]
```

Issues:

1. As you can see, the scheduled date is same as the old date.
2. `TODO` has changed to `DONE`. It should stay in `TODO` with the new scheduled dates.

This issue started appearing recently.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use `C-c C-s` to schedule.

Answer (score 4):

Remove the space between + and 1m.